# Hosting a new asp.net MVC web application on IIS 7, will show the following error "Page can not be displayed" when accessing its home page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

Inside my Visual Studio 2012 i created a new asp.net MVC web application, with simple Home controller, and its basic Index view. Then using VS 2012 i created a web deployment package (generate a .zip file), then i did the following:-

1. inside IIS 7.0 i created a new web site on port 4377.
2. then i moved the mvc files inside the new web site as follow:-

[image]
3. but when i tried browser the following url `http://localhost/4377` i got the following error:-

[image]

Instead of being redirected to the Index view.
so i am not sure what could be the problem?
i have check the anonymous access and it is enabled:-

[image]

also here is my web.config:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

so can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

here is my routing.config:-

```
{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: What does your RouteConfig look like?

Comment: @SBFFrancies it contains the defualt routing code. will update my question with it.. now i try deploying the same mvc on another server and i was able to access it.. so i think the problem is within IIS